# How can i download my aws key file?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, backup

I asked a freelancer to migrate the website from staging to live server and they perform the migration, but now I want to back up the files and DB I need a pem file, which the freelancer never gave me. 
What do I do? I don't know the FTP details also.
How can I backup my website files and DB?
The website is hosted on aws Ec2-Linux?

Comment: Does this EC2 instance run in your AWS account, or the freelancer's account?

Comment: its my account  but i have given the aws credentials to those freelancer

Answer (score 0):

You can create a snapshot of the EBS.

```
aws ec2 create-snapshot --volume-id vol-1234567890abcdef0 --description "This is my root volume snapshot"
```

Reminder: EBS Volume snapshots are stored in S3 but they're not visble to user through the bucket.

(You must have IAM Permissions to EC2 to perform this action)

Comment: This answer doesn't solve the problem. Do you to say there's some way to replace the PEM key from a snapshot?

Comment: The answer was more directed towards his other question of "How can I backup my website files and DB" -- If you create a snapshot and attach that EBS to another EC2 instance you can create another PEM file.

Comment: Without a pem file they can't ssh in probably can't run that command.

Comment: i can't ssh because i don't have they key, the freelancers have the key and ftp details

Comment: You don't need the key here to SSH. As long as you have access to the Console, create a snapshot, attach that snapshot to another EC2 instance, and change the PEM key. Here is the AWS Document on how to create a new key. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ec2-key-pairs.html#replacing-lost-key-pair

Comment: The comment by @RyanWilliamWest should really be an answer. Suggest you edit your answer to incorporate it more fully Ryan.